# setting up v-autocomplete with search function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Trying to setup v-autocomplete, without a watcher, the flow would be:

1. Type a string, value is accepted by function
2. Function searches api for string and returns a list
3. List is put into "entries"
4. Computed property "tagsFound" is reevaluated.
5. "tagsFound" are displayed (since they are `:items`)
   The main difference between the docs [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes) and my code is my attempt to do this without a watcher rather with a simple function.
   Relevant code:

```
<v-autocomplete
          v-model="newTag"
          :items="tagsFound"
          :loading="loading"
          :search-input.sync="search"
          color="white"
          hide-no-data
          hide-selected
          :placeholder="$t('search_terms.new_tag')"
        ></v-autocomplete>
    ...
    data() {
      return {
        newTag: '',
        entries: [],
    ....
    methods: {
    ...
     async search(term){
        this.query.term = term
        this.entries = await this.searchTerms(this.query)
      },
    ...
    computed: {
      tagsFound(){
        return this.entries
      }
    }
```

**Expected behavior** is search for the term typed and display the results as a dropdown.
**Actual behavior** is that it does not search and therefore does not display anything.

Comment: I give you a hint. Where and when do you fire `search` ?

Comment: Not sure where you are going with this, but would appreciate info, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sync` modifier effectively makes a prop behave like `v-model`, so just like with `v-model` there's a prop and an event. The value needs to be a property, not a method, so `:search-input.sync="search"` doesn't make sense if `search` is a method.

The `tagsFound` computed property in your example isn't really doing anything. If you're just going to return `entries` you might as well just use `entries` directly in your template.

Not sure why you would want to do this without a `watch` but it can be done, either by splitting `search-input.sync` into a prop/event pair or by using a computed property with a getter and setter. The example below uses the latter approach.

```js
function fakeServer (search) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([
        'Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Brown', 'Blue', 'Pink', 'Black'
      ].filter(c => c.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())))
    }, 1000)
  }) 
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data () {
    return {
      newTag: '',
      entries: [],
      queryTerm: ''
    }
  },

  computed: {
    search: {
      get () {
        return this.queryTerm
      },
      
      set (searchInput) {
        if (this.queryTerm !== searchInput) {
          this.queryTerm = searchInput
          this.loadEntries()
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
  created () {
    this.loadEntries()
  },

  methods: {
    async loadEntries () {
      this.entries = await fakeServer(this.queryTerm || '')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.5.16/dist/vuetify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.5.16/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="newTag"
      :items="entries"
      :search-input.sync="search"
    ></v-autocomplete>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In this part, you bind `search-input` to an `async` method, this is wrong. You need to bind `search-input` to a data field and create a watch over it.

```
<v-autocomplete
          :search-input.sync="search"
></v-autocomplete>
```

Define your component like below:

```
data: function(){
   return {
        newTag: '',
        entries: [],
        searchInput: null     
   }
},
watch: {
    searchInput(val){
        this.entries = await this.searchTerms(val)
    } 
}
```

And v-autocomplete template:

```
<v-autocomplete
          v-model="newTag"
          :items="tagsFound"
          :loading="loading"
          :search-input.sync="searchInput"
          color="white"
          hide-no-data
          hide-selected
          :placeholder="$t('search_terms.new_tag')"
        ></v-autocomplete>
```

[This is a working example](https://codepen.io/al1b/pen/dBgGJy?editors=1010) I created on CodePen

Comment: I am aware I can do this as per the docs, I would like to avoid using a `watch` method if possible.

Comment: You could use `update:search-input` event instead of a watcher